# Fault reading of background color

Tags: javascript, css, colors, background

I have css file with property: "background:#f9f9f9;". The div has the right background color but when I read it the result is empty (""). The function then changes the background color and when I read it again it shows me: "background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(249, 249, 249)". The new color is right but it was shown only after I changed the color using js.
Why does it happens? Is there any way to fix it?
(I know I can initialize it manually using js with the right color, and I'm going to do it until I find the right solution).

Edit: inserted code.

```
.cLiftsDiv {
float:left;
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 15%;
border:1px solid #111111;
background:#f9f9f9;
border-radius: 5px;
height: 80%;

cursor: default;

/* to be unselectable */
-moz-user-select: -moz-none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
margin: 2% 2%;
position:relative;
}
```

JS functions:

```
var items = new Array("Lifts");
var elem = document.getElementById("mainMonitor");

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i)
{
    var tempDiv = document.createElement("div");
    tempDiv.id = items[i] + "Div";
    tempDiv.className = "c" + items[i] + "Div";
    var tempInnerDiv = document.createElement("div");
    tempInnerDiv.innerHTML = items[i];
    tempDiv.appendChild(tempInnerDiv);

    tempDiv.onmouseover = hoverDiv;
    elem.appendChild(tempDiv);
}

function hoverDiv()
{
var elem = document.getElementById(this.id);
alert("background: " + elem.style.background);
if (elem.style.background != "#aaaaaa")
{
    //elem.style.background = "#cccccc";
}
}
```

I use firefox (and it doesn't work too in chrome).

Comment: How are you reading the style? Do you use `getComputedStyle(...)`?

Comment: Looks to be a browser issue, Works fine here

Comment: I think the problem is in your css code. I am 100% sure about it. Please post the code.

Answer (score 0):

We need more code to help here but is background color which works fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
   span.highlight
    {
      background-color:yellow;
    }
</style>
</head>

 <body>
<p>
<span class="highlight">This is a text.</span> This is a text. This is a text. This is a text. This is a text. This is a text. This is a text. This is a text. This is a text.      <span class="highlight">This is a text.</span>
 </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Working with JavaScript alerting the color:  [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/liammccann1992/GRCZQ/1/)

[image: The pop up]

You should try this instead:

```
//On page ready
var color = "#fff";
$("item selctor").css("background-color",color);
```

Comment: The alert is blank for me.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox and IE report nothing (the alert is blank). Opera does show the color, `rgb(255, 255, 0)`. And Chrome shows all the background, `rgb(255, 255, 0) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box`

Comment: Try above that should be a simple solution